# How to broadcast and assign a series of values across all columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign, broadcasting

I know this must be easy but I can't figure it out or find an existing answer on this...

Say I have this dataframe...

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
             A   B   C   D
2013-01-01 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-02 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-04 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-05 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-06 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

It's easy to set the values of one series...

```
>>> df.loc[:, 'A'] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index=dates)
>>> df
            A   B   C   D
2013-01-01  1 NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-02  2 NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-03  3 NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-04  4 NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-05  5 NaN NaN NaN
2013-01-06  6 NaN NaN NaN
```

But how do I set the values of all columns using broadcasting?

```
>>> default_values = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index=dates)
>>> df.loc[:, :] = default_values
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 189, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 651, in _setitem_with_indexer
    value=value)
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3693, in setitem
    return self.apply('setitem', **kwargs)
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3581, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 940, in setitem
    values[indexer] = value
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (6,4)
```

Other than these ways:

```
>>> for s in df:
...     df.loc[:, s] = default_values
...
```

Or:

```
>>> df.loc[:, :] = np.vstack([default_values]*4).T
```

UPDATE:

Or:

```
>>> df.loc[:, :] = default_values.values.reshape(6,1)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use numpy `broadcasting`

```
s =  pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index=dates)
df.loc[:,:] = s.values[:,None]
```

---

Using index matching

```
df.loc[:] = pd.concat([s]*df.columns.size, axis=1)
```

Comment: Well there you go!

Comment: Thanks.  This is similar to the additional solution I added to the question.  As per my comment on @Andrey Portnoy's answer, the danger with using numpy arrays is if the index of `default_values` is not the same as `df.index`.

Comment: @Bill well then you might make a frame and assign it directly , see edit

Comment: Bingo!  That's it.  Thanks v. much.

Comment: The index matching will cause `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` for me, presumably because the concated from-series-df creates identical column names.
The workaround I personally use is to make an intermediate step
`concat_df = pd.concat([s]*df.columns.size, axis=1)` and then `concat_df.columns = df.columns` - not sure if this is due to a version change or some other reason? Happy to get some enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way has already provided in Pandas: calling `.add` method and specify which direction (axis) you want to add new values.

```
In [7]: df.fillna(0).add(default_values, axis=0)
Out[7]:
              A    B    C    D
2013-01-01  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2013-01-02  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
2013-01-03  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
2013-01-04  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
2013-01-05  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
2013-01-06  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
```

Note: in newer [pandas versions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/ops.py#L1544-L1559), you can just do `df.add(default_values, axis=0, fill_value=0)`, basically a syntax improvement to avoiding chained methods.

Note that if the index-alignment idea of pandas applies here: considering this case where the new values only covers 4 out of 5 rows of the target dataframe

```
In [37]: default_values = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(5,5)) + np.nan, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

In [39]: df.fillna(0).add(default_values, axis=0)
Out[39]:
     0    1    2    3    4
a  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
b  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
d  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The row `e` which is not found in the new value Series, becomes `NaN`

Comment: That makes sense, but I think OP wants to 'overwrite values'. This case would work for `NaN`s only, and other values would get *old_values+new_values*. But good approach anyway :)

Comment: That's good.  Works in most cases - when values are addable for example.  One exception is when default_values contains values for indices that are not in df.  Then you get unwanted `NaN`s!

Comment: @Bill, very good point. In my opinion that is intentional, and follows the general index-alignment design in pandas.  I will add an example shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I landed here looking for a solution to both creating new columns and assigning a single default value per column (not per row).  While this isn't exactly what the OP requested, I found this solution works well.  Please comment and redirect to a specific thread for this if appropriate:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
default_values = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['A','B','C','D'] ).to_dict()
df = df.assign( **default_values )   # note use of ** notation (kwargs)
In [97]: df                                                                                                                                      
Out[97]: 
            A  B  C  D
2013-01-01  1  2  3  4
2013-01-02  1  2  3  4
2013-01-03  1  2  3  4
2013-01-04  1  2  3  4
2013-01-05  1  2  3  4
2013-01-06  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you muchly for this!! It is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with NumPy:

```
nvalues = 6
ncolumns = 4
default_values = np.repeat(np.arange(nvalues), ncolumns).reshape(nvalues, ncolumns)

df.loc[:, :] = default_values
```

However this doesn't address your hope for broadcasting on the Pandas side. I don't know of any tricks to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to the second solution in the question.  I just can't believe that the broadcasting doesn't work in pandas...

Comment: The downside with using only numpy is that the order of `default_values` might not be the same and therefore the index of default_values should be used ideally.

Comment: @Bill I don't think I understand. What do you mean by "order might not be the same"?

Comment: Say if default_values is a series that has been reversed (sorted descending) then pandas would still assign the values to the correct rows by matching the index values first.  Whereas numpy 'blindly' pastes in the values in the order given.

Comment: @Bill I see. Thanks for taking the time to explain.